# etale morphism between sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

We knoe that if $f$ and $  f\circ g$ are both etale morphisms between schemes, then so is $g$. Does this statement hold for etale morphisms between sheavs on etale site over a scheme?
More generally, if we do it in a general category and etale is replaced by any other particular property, say  $P$, satifies

(1) compositions of $P$  morphisms is a $P$  morphism,

(2) pullbacks of a $P$  morphism by a morphism is a $P$  morphism and

(3) if $f$ and $  f\circ g$ are both $P$ morphisms. then so is $g$.

And we similarly define $P$  morphisms between sheaves on the $P$ site over a object, i.e. $F\to G$ is $P$ if the pull back by any $h_X\to G$ is representable by some $h_Y\to h_X$ with $Y\to X$ a $P$ morphism. Does the statement (3) still hold?
For example, the category is the category of affine schemes and $P$ is open immersion, then Sheaves are schemes and $P$ is still open immmersion. And (3) still holds. I'm afraid all of them are wrong, but I need some counterexamples.

Comment: What is your definition of étale morphism of sheaves?

Comment: Replace this $P$ by etale

Comment: Your definition is not the usual one – it is too restrictive if your site is the category of affine schemes – but it does have the advantage of making it easy to prove the cancellation property you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be any class of morphisms in a category with pullbacks such that $P$ is stable under  composition and pullbacks. Let $g : X \to Y$, $f : Y \to Z$ be two morphisms such that $\Delta_f \in P$ and $f \circ g \in P$. Let us prove $g \in P$: We factor $g$ as
$$X \xrightarrow{\Gamma_g} X \times_{f \circ g,Z,f} Y \xrightarrow{\mathrm{pr_2}}Y$$
We have $\mathrm{pr}_2 \in P$ because this is the pullback of $(f \circ g : X \to Z) \in P$ along $f$. There is a cartesian square which shows that $\Gamma_g$ is a pullback of $\Delta_f : Y \to Y \times_{Z} Y$, so that $\Gamma_g \in P$. Hence, $g \in P$.